# PThread - Thread Exiting early despite calling pthread_join

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, pthread-join

I have implemented PThreads in a fairly elementary way as:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class ThreadParameter
{
public:
char symbol_char;
int count;
};

void* print_char (void* param)
{

ThreadParameter* p = (ThreadParameter*)param;

for (int i=0; i< p->count; i++)
{
cout<< p->symbol_char <<endl;
i++;
}
return NULL;
}

int main ()
{
pthread_t thread1_id;

ThreadParameter param1;

param1.symbol_char = 'X';
param1.count = 27;

pthread_create (&thread1_id, NULL, &print_char, &param1);

int i = 0;

while (i<10)
{
cout<<"O"<<endl;
i++;
}

pthread_join(thread1_id,NULL);

return 0;
}
```

And its output is not showing the expected nos of X. Am I doing some mistake in calling join function or what? Thanks for help.

[image: Output]

P.S: I have tried various values of X from 5 to 20, but it always gives me lesser than the desired numbers of X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incrementing `i` twice in `print_char()`.

Change

```
for (int i=0; i< p->count; i++)
{
    cout<< p->symbol_char <<endl;
    i++;
}
```

into

```
for (int i=0; i< p->count; i++)
{
    cout<< p->symbol_char <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Ouch!! Such a bad bug. Awful of me. Really Sorry

Comment: This looks Ok to me. I would however suggest to use C++11 and the new standard way to program threads in C++ if possible.

Comment: Can I use it on Windows/VS 2010 as well? Any tutorial etc for that please

Comment: I don't think so. You need a more recent version of Visual Studio. VS2013 would do it already I think.  Pick a more recent one if possible. VS2010 is quite old. For a tutorial check this one https://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/12/16/cpp-11-thread-tutorial/

Comment: I have 15 as well. Thank you so much!!